# Rxjs retry() not retrying

Tags: rxjs

I'm not sure if I'm missunderstanding this operator, but I've write this piece of code to see if I can make it work.
Basically, I'm trying to make it retry the function call 3 times max if there's an error, but it only gets called once even when the error is thrown:

```js
    simulateHttpRequest() {
      const shouldSucceed = Math.random() < 0.1; // 10% chance of success
      if (shouldSucceed) {
        return of('Random response');
      } else {
        return throwError(() => new Error('Random error'));
      }
    }
    
    makeCall() {
      this.simulateHttpRequest().pipe(
        retry(3) // Retry 3 times?
      ).subscribe({
        next: o => console.log(o),
        error: o => console.error(o) // Error is triggered inmediately
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `retry()` operator resubscribes to the same source Observable returned from `simulateHttpRequest()`. It can't call the method itself.

If you want to call the method for every attempt you can wrap it with `defer()`:

```
defer(() => this.simulateHttpRequest()).pipe(
   retry(3),
)
```

Comment: While martin's code is correct, I think you should keep your retry without the defer here and wrap the whole body of your `simulateHttpRequest` with a `defer`. That'll technically represent the truth of what's happening in a better way I reckon. I know the result is the same, but I just think your mocked function doesn't represent the truth and therefore leads to incoherent runtime code which is too bad as the code could be cleaner :)